# Load screen image sometimes doesn't display

Tags: silverlight-4.0, splash-screen

I have a custom splashscreen in my Silverlight 4 project which sometimes does not display the image element.  If there something I need to do in order to ensure this image is displayed every time when the load screen is used?

```
<StackPanel xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,100,0,0">
    <Image Source="../Assets/Logo.png" 
       Height="200" Width="200"          
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Center"          
       Margin="15" />
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle Name="rectBorder" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="#FFC8C8C8" 
              Height="7" Width="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <Rectangle Name="rectBar" Fill="#FFC8C8C8" 
              Height="7" Width="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you load the silverlight object, the browser is told to download your XAP file, the XAML splash file, and then the Logo.png. This PNG is loaded last in the queue.

To fix that, try preloading an invisible image before embedding the  tag.

```
<body>

  <img src="../Assets/Logo.png" style="width:0;height:0;" />

  <object>
  ... // your xap stuff goes here
  </object>

</body>
```

Comment: Excellent. I didn't test this solution, I just figured that since browsers typically don't allow more than 2 connections open to the same domain, your PNG is loaded too late. Glad it worked!